# A property of continuous functions

Tags: continuity

A function $f : [a,b] \to [a,b]$ is continuous for all $x \in [a,b].$ Prove that there exists a $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = c.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use intermediate value theorem on $g(x) = f(x) - x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be  continuous, such that $f(a)f(b)<0$. Then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$.